# Create a YAML schema from a given YAML file

Tags: yaml, schema

I am trying to generate a Yaml schema from a big fat YML file. I have looked at a few tools like Hackolade but the functionality is blocked.

Has anyone used a tool/script for the same purpose?

Comment: While YAML does define [schemas](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#chapter-10-recommended-schemas), the spec doesn't say how they are to be described. You need to be more specific in what you want to create.